# A Bot which can get through the browsers unsafe error into gmail app

Tags: selenium-webdriver, compiler-errors

How do you make a bot that gets past through the brownser unsafe error and log into the gmail through a proxy to start sending emails?

I did try making a bot using selenium but i cannot get through the browsers error (unsafe)

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and the snapshot of _**unsafe error**_